# ¿Como puedo obtener una imagen enviada por un usuario con discord js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filesystem, discord.js

Estoy tratando de obtener la imagen enviada por un usuario en  un canal de discord de tal manera que pueda manipularla posteriormente, no me es posible obtenerla por msg.content, he intentado de varias forma pero no he podido hacerlo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, ¿Que has intentado? ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de código con el que estas trabajando? Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: Para que la etiqueta discord.py? Creo que la pregunta es de discord.js, no discord.py...

Comment: Si estoy en lo correcto, por favor edita la pregunta, quita la etiqueta discord.py y agrega la etiqueta discord.js.